# Misleading $R^2$ values due to clusters on the opposite side of the regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, r-squared

I have a regression model for density predictions and I eventually did a model that I do not trust.
[image: First model]

It gives me an $R^2$ of 0.93

I am not sure what to call this phenomenon: is this heteroscedasticity? I did the Breusch-Pagan test and it showed that there is none.

To investigate this further, I split the models into two and re-trained. I got two $R^2$ values, one at 0.86 and one at 0.85. Can someone please help me in criticising the attached plot? why is this plot giving misleading $R^2$ values? How can this be improved and this effect be excluded?

Comment: How are you calculating the $R^2$ value? If you’re calculating correctly (I assume you are), why would you consider it misleading? (I have my thoughts but want to know yours.)

Comment: @Dave I am using the proportion of the variance in the dependent variable (Response) that is predictable from the independent variable (vPred)

I think the reason why it should not be trusted is because the variance is too damn high to start with. Here is the code snippet:

SS_X = sum((vPred-mean(vPred)).^2);
SS_Y = sum((Response-mean(Response)).^2);
SS_XY = sum((vPred-mean(vPred)).*(Response-mean(Response)));
v_R2 = SS_XY/sqrt(SS_X*SS_Y);

Comment: @Dave check original comment, I pressed enter, thinking that I will go to a new line

Comment: What do you mean that the variance is too high to start with?

Comment: @Dave within one group the variance does not change a lot. Between spruce and beech there is a significantly higher variance

Comment: But what do you find problematic? I'm seeing a mostly good fit with a few large errors that seem not to be enough to tank the overall $R^2$ value. (I'm actually susprised those bad misses don't do more damage, but perhaps I'm underestimating how many points have near-perfect predictions.)

Comment: @Dave There are quite a lot of good predictions and the clusters do appear to scatter around the least square line. My fear is that this is a red flag for a reviewer (as anything can be). Wanted to get ahead and write some self-criticizing comments...

Comment: Aside: there's a violation of the assumed normality of residuals as distributed vertically about the regression line (the cluster of observations centered around 600 actual are skewed high on the predictions, and the cluster centered around 730 actual are skewed low on the predictions).

Comment: I think you're worrying about the wrong thing? $R^2$ is what it is; the implication of your plot to me is that you may be able to find a better model to catch some variability you're missing, but I can't see any information here that lets us advise more precisely on that. The answer may depend on biological expertise in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *ecological fallacy* may apply here.  Certainly *partial correlation* applies. The fit within any of the 3 (not two) clusters is much poorer than in the aggregate. You’ll need to decide, as @Nick Cox seems to say, whether results controlling for (holding constant) cluster deserve more focus than overall fit does. A pretty instructive exemplar.